# Is Session Affinity maintained by apache load balancer after one instance down

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7, mod-jk, apache2.4

I deployed my project in 3 tomcats named tomcat1,tomcat2,tomcat3. Those are configured with tomcat cluster.
Session Affinity works fine if all tomcats are up and running.
If Tomcat1 down and it contain session,if client requests that session those session details will come through tomcat2.
But,next request goes to tomcat3.So,I lost some data.
So,Here Session Affinity not working.
In the previous scenario when Tomcat1 was down all requests goes to tomcat1 only.
Why this occurs when tomcat1 down?

Here is my workers.properties file

```
worker.list=loadbal

worker.loadbal.type=lb

worker.loadbal.balance_workers=jvm1,jvm2,jvm3,jvm4

#worker.stat.type=status

#worker.loadbal.sticky_session=True
#worker.loadbal.sticky_session_force=True

#Define worker corresponding to a tomcat server node

worker.jvm1.port=8010

worker.jvm1.host=xxx.xxx.x.xxx

worker.jvm1.type=ajp13

worker.jvm1.jvm_route=jvm1

#Define worker corresponding to a tomcat server node

worker.jvm2.port=8011

worker.jvm2.host=xxx.xxx.x.103

worker.jvm2.type=ajp13

worker.jvm2.jvm_route=jvm2

worker.jvm3.port=8012

worker.jvm3.host=xxx.xxx.x.73

worker.jvm3.type=ajp13

#worker.jvm3.jvm_route=jvm3

worker.jvm4.port=8014

worker.jvm4.host=xxx.xxx.x.103

worker.jvm4.type=ajp13

#worker.jvm4.jvm_route=jvm4
```

try with any application which create session.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This achieved by using worker.redirect=routeid.

if you mention this in worker.properties file it works fine.